# Lock free MPMC Ring buffer implementation in C

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, circular-list

I have written a lock free MPMC FIFO in C based on a ring buffer. It uses gcc's atomic built-ins to achieve thread safety. The queue is designed to return -1 if it's full on enqueue or empty on dequeue.

After some feedback, I've changed by design. I have tested this code to work, but testing multithreaded code is hardly enough to prove it's correct.

```
struct queue
{
    void** buf;
    size_t num;
    uint64_t writePos;
    uint64_t readPos;
};

queue_t* createQueue(size_t num)
{
    struct queue* new = xmalloc(sizeof(*new));
    new->buf = xmalloc(sizeof(void*) * num);
    memset(new->buf, 0, sizeof(void*)*num);
    new->readPos = 0;
    new->writePos = 0;
    new->num = num;
    return new;
}

void destroyQueue(queue_t* queue)
{
    if(queue)
    {
        xfree(queue->buf);
        xfree(queue);
    }
}

int enqueue(queue_t* queue, void* item)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < kNumTries; i++)
    {
        if(__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&queue->buf[queue->writePos % queue->num], NULL, item))
        {
            __sync_fetch_and_add(&queue->writePos, 1);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void* dequeue(queue_t* queue)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < kNumTries; i++)
    {
        void* value = queue->buf[queue->readPos % queue->num];
        if(value && __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&queue->buf[queue->readPos % queue->num], value, NULL))
        {
            __sync_fetch_and_add(&queue->readPos, 1);
            return value;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

(link to the [previous iteration](http://pastebin.com/c82qqDsX))

Comment: Also check out Relacy for thread-safeness-testing.  No guarantees on its accuracy -- http://www.1024cores.net/home/relacy-race-detector

Answer (score 4):

Did you test it?

I think you have a problem if a thread calls `enqueue` and is interrupted
just before the `memcpy`, having calculated `pos` to be slot-1.  If another
thread now calls `enqueue` and completes it will write to slot-2 and increment the `pendingRead` counter, leaving
slot-1 still unwritten.  If a third thread now reads before the first thread
can complete its write, the reader will read from the unwritten slot-1.  This
is becase the second thread correctly set the queue to say there is a pending
read (slot-2) but `dequeue` assumes the data must be in the next available
slot according to `readPos`.

A few other comments:

1. `queue_t` is defined (elsewhere) as a pointer type. I prefer pointers to be
   explicit.
2. You have mixed use of `struct queue *` and `queue_t`
3. Return from `malloc` is not checked.
4. `buf` in `struct queue` should be `void*` not `char **`
5. Why are `writePos` and `readPos` of type `uint64_t` and not `size_t`?
   After all, `num` is `size_t`.  Why the difference?
6. Loss of precision assigning `num` in `createQueue`

Comment: I rewrote the queue in an attempt to solve the problem you mentioned. `writePos` and `readPos` are uint64_t because even on 32 bit systems they need to be 64 bit.

Comment: It would be nice if you could take a look at the new code.

Comment: In `dequeue`, You need to cache the value of `queue->readPos % queue->num` to protect against a change in `readPos` between assigning `value` and the following `if(...)`.  In addition, you are using a busy-loop to wait for space/new-data; this is not usually considered a good idea but can sometimes be done - it depends upon your application (but personally I'd be suspicious of code like that if I met it in the wild). I don't see any other problem, but as you say, spotting race conditions is difficult; there might still be something wrong...

Answer (score 3):

1. it seems that `enqueue()` can leave the queue with holes: `(readPos+1)%num == NULL` and `(readPos+1)%num != NULL`. I'll try to explain with an example.

   - the system has 2 producers threads, `P1` and `P2` and one consumer thread, `C1`. `readPos == 0` and `writePos == 1`.
   - `P1` calls `enqueue()`, successfully executes `compare_and_swap` and gets preempted. `readPos == 0` and `writePos == 1`.
   - `C1` gets the CPU, dequeues 2 items, `buf[0]` and `buf[1]`, and gets preempted. `readPos == 2` and `writePos == 1`.
   - `P2` gets the CPU, enqueues 1 item in `buf[1]` and is preempted. `readPos == 2` and `writePos == 2`.
   - `P1` resumes, increments `writePos`. now `readPos == 2` and `writePos == 3`.
   - `P1` enqueues next item in `buf[3]`. `readPos == 2` and `writePos == 4`.
   - `C1` resumes. now `readPos == 2`, `writePos == 3` and the buffer has a hole (since `buf[2] == NULL`). `C1` is stuck at `readPos == 2`. it can not dequeue items from `buf[3]` onward.

the system remains in this state till the producers wrap the buffer around and writes an item to `buf[2]`. replacing `fetch_and_add` with a `compare_and_swap` should help here.

2. a particularly unlucky producer may fail the `compare_and_swap` all the `kNumTries` times and return `-1` from `enqueue()`, even though the `buf` is not full. you can perhaps introduce a variable such as `enqueue_in_progress` and busy wait on a `compare_and_swap(&enqueue_in_progress, 0, 1)` at the beginning of `enqueue()`. this will ensure only one producer can enter the body of `enqueue()` at a time.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your `enqueue()` does not guarantee progress by at least one thread, in case the thread that just enqueued into the `writePos`, before adjusting the index is being suspended by some interrupt or system scheduler. In such case all threads trying to `enqueue()` will wait until the first one wake up and increment the `writePos`.

You might want to advance the `writePos` in case the CAS failed, and it is smaller than `readPos - 1`.